# Controlling div order in single / double column layout? Is it even possible?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want a double column layout for wider screens and a single column layout for narrower screens.

In a double column layout, I'd like "left" and "right" items to stack up underneath each other.

In a single column layout, I'd like the items to follow the order they're written in the html.

To demonstrate, both these samples should look the same in the double column version:

**HTML 1**

```
<div class="left">left one</div>
<div class="left">left two</div>
<div class="left">left three</div>
<div class="right">right one</div>
<div class="right">right two</div>
<div class="right">right three</div>
```

**HTML 2**

```
<div class="left">left one</div>
<div class="left">left two</div>
<div class="right">right one</div>
<div class="left">left three</div>
<div class="right">right two</div>
<div class="right">right three</div>
```

**CSS**

I've tried CSS like this, but it doesn't work because a "right" floated item won't go to the top of the page after 2 or more "left" floated items.

```
<style>

.left {float:left;}
.right {float:right;}

@media (max-width:991px){
    .left,
    .right  {
        width:100%;
    }
}
@media (min-width:992px){
    .left {
        width:60%;
        float:left;
    }
    .right {
        width:30%;
        float:right;
    }
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: can you create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ also with the colors in css and might try to explain what is state of the art and what the expected outcome cause I don't really get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these rules will do the job:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .left {
        width: 60%;
    }
    .right {
        width: 30%;
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
}
```

To make right items float properly you can set them `float: none` for wide dimensions and `marging-left: 10%` will take care of proper 10% gap between columns.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3dkmt84n/

<sub>Note: in demo `min-width` is reduced to 400px for demonstration purpose.</sub>

Comment: Is there a way to make this work when you have more .right than .left divs? I have tried reversing the css rules (so .left is inline-block and unfloated on full size screen) but can't get it to work :(    http://jsfiddle.net/n467un0c/

Comment: Maybe something like this. Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/n467un0c/15/ `.right` is not floated anymore but has `margin-left: 70%` and width 30%. `.left` still has float: left.